# shared LVM storage between KVM virtuals

Tags: kvm, qemu

I'm messing around with KVM and different storage options for sharing between virtual machines. I have an LVM volume group defined as a storage pool for `libvirt`. I've defined a volume and attached it to two test VMs as a virtio disk. Here's virsh dumpxml

```
<disk type='block' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
  <source dev='/dev/kvm_storage/vm_shared'/>
  <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
  <shareable/>
  <alias name='virtio-disk0'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
</disk>
```

I can read/write files, but they do not stay in sync between the two virtuals unless I unmount then remount. Is this even supported?

Comment: I built I high availability system, albeit several years ago, using two machines sharing a volume group. Our caveat was that only one machine could import and make active the volume group at a time.
Don't recall if the second could be made read only or not.   

I would suggest one serve via nfs or samba and the other use,mount as client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an [clustered file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustered_file_system).

I do not know what filesystem you are using. But with a standard file system this is not possible and has nothing to do KVM or LVM.

An other solution would be to use a network filesystem like `nfs` or `cifs`.

Comment: or use `smb` samba to be compatible with Windows VMs.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use those levels :

On physical Host :

- KVM level : second disk for VM marked as "Shared storage" in Virt-manager properties (only disk type "raw" is supported. qcow2 is not supported as "shareable" in vm disk edit screen and virt-manager will not allow you to click "apply" when you tick the "shareable" box)

On VMs :

- level 0 : DLM (like disk logical management I think) # service dlm start ; Linux packages to install
- level 1 : LVM management
- level 2 : GFS2 filesystem formatted on your LVM logical volume

Answer (score 0):

A disk used by a vm at the same time.Otherwise,the filesystem on the disk will be damaged!
    You can use NAS/NFS/SMB etc network filesystem to share files.